# Move Docker Containers via export/import: lost Configuration like start command

Tags: configuration, docker, migration

I want to move containers from one host to another. The containers have updated data in their filesystem, so I do not want to move the original images (docker save) but containers (using docker export).

So I use

```
docker export l4bnode > l4bnode.tar
```

on the old host, copy the file to new host, and import image

```
cat l4bnode.tar | docker import - andi/l4bnode
```

on the new one. But.. it looks like all the configuration data I had in the Dockerfile (and that I also could specify/had specified in the command line when running the container) is lost. I tried

```
docker run andi/l4bnode
```

and get

```
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
```

Using docker inspect, I see that all data on the imported image is empty, though it is set on the exported running container. I mainly am missing startup command, working directory, environment variables and exposed ports (some of which I have to change then due to the migration and new environment).

How can I apply the original configuration on the new host, or preferrably, migrate it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) the current container state as new image. Then use save/load on the new image.

That being said this is something you generally should try to avoid. Runtime data should be kept in volumes, any configuration changes should happen via Dockerfile rebuilds.